# Finding matching values using excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

Without using excel built-in filter or pivot table function, I want to extract some results using vba. Consider the following example: given data in coloumn A and B, I want to be able to input "a" in C1 and using the vba to get in Column D all the corresponding values from column B (1,3,5). If I input "b", I get 2, 6, so on. Thanks.  [image]
[image]

Comment: Not even an Excel formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Sub GenerateMatches()

With ActiveSheet
FinalRowA = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

InputLetter = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 3)
NextRow = 1

For i = 1 To FinalRowA
If .Cells(i, 1) = InputLetter Then
.Cells(NextRow, 4) = .Cells(i, 2)
NextRow = NextRow + 1
End If

Next i

End With

End Sub
```

Obviously, you can make this alot more dynamic and faster, but this should get the job done.

Comment: You should add this to clear column D before running:      

    `Columns("D:D").Select
    Selection.ClearContents`

Answer (score 0):

Enter the following event macro in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim D1 As Range, K As Long
    Dim N As Long, NN As Long
    Set D1 = Range(Range("D1"), Range("D1").End(xlDown))
    If Intersect(Target, Range("C1")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    v = Target.Value
    K = 1
    D1.Clear
    NN = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For N = 1 To NN
        If v = Cells(N, "A").Value Then
            Cells(K, "D").Value = Cells(N, "B").Value
            K = K + 1
        End If
    Next
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to install and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

Macros must be enabled for this to work!

**B.T.W.**

You can do the same thing with formulas and no VBA - like VLOOKUP on steriods!

Answer (score 0):

I understand when you say you didn't want to use filters or Pivots. But Formulas?

If something is possible with formulas then why VBA?

Paste this Array Formula in `Cell D1` and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd> and pull it down.

`=IF(ISERROR(INDEX($A$1:$B$7,SMALL(IF($A$1:$A$7=$C$1,ROW($A$1:$A$7)),ROW(1:1)),2)),"",INDEX($A$1:$B$7,SMALL(IF($A$1:$A$7=$C$1,ROW($A$1:$A$7)),ROW(1:1)),2))`

**Screenshot**
[image]